# Not able to display data in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, linq-to-entities

When I click on an Edit link for a particular record I want to retrieve data for that id  from my controller in a view razor and display in a form for editing. But it's throwing an error. It's retrieving data from my database, but as soon as I hit the view it throws an error in each field:

Error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'AppName' and no extension method 'AppName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
Source Error:
Line 8:      <fieldset>   
Line 9:      <div class="editor-label grid_2">
Line 10:         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppName) :
Line 11:     </div>
Line 12:     <div class="editor-field grid_3">
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

Controller called when click on Edit link:

```
  [Authorize]
        public ActionResult UpdateAPIForm(string id,string appname)
        {
            try
            {
                var a = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                var context = new ndCorp_SiteEntities();

                var viewModel = (from du in context.DevUserInfoes
                                join dc in context.DevContactInfoes on du.UserName equals dc.UserName
                                join dm in context.DevMarketplaceInfoes on du.UserName equals dm.UserName
                                join dm1 in context.DevMarketplaceInfoes on dc.AppName equals dm1.AppName
                                where (du.UserName == a && dc.AppName == appname )
                                select new NewAPIFormModel()
                                    { 
                                        AppName = dc.AppName, 
                                        Email = dc.DevEmail ,
                                        OrgName = dc.OrgName ,
                                        DevName = dc.DevName ,
                                        ClientID = dc.ClientID ,
                                        ClientSecret = dc.ClientSecret ,
                                        RedUrl = dc.Url ,
                                        AppNameForMP = dm.NewAppNameForMP ,
                                        AppDesc = dm.AppDesc ,
                                        DoYouAgree = dm.DispInPublicMP.Value ,
                                        mobil = dm.ChkMobility.Value ,
                                        legal = dm.ChkLegal.Value ,
                                        docmgm = dm.ChkDocMgm.Value ,
                                        finser = dm.ChkFinSer.Value ,
                                        microoff = dm.ChkMicOff.Value  ,
                                        saleforce = dm.ChkSalesForce.Value ,
                                        scanner = dm.ChkScanMF.Value ,
                                        wordper = dm.ChkWordPer.Value ,
                                        deskext = dm.ChkDeskExt.Value ,
                                        other = dm.ChkOther.Value ,
                                        //updlogo = dm.UpdLogo,
                                       // pricing =Convert.ToString(dm.Pricing),
                                        pricingURL = dm.UrlPricing,
                                        contactinfo = dm.Contact,
                                    }).ToList();
                                //select dc;
                return View(viewModel);
                //return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                TempData["msg"] = ex.Message.ToString();
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<N.Models.NewAPIFormModel>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>   
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppName) :
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AppName, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
     <div class="editor-label1 grid_2">
        Must be unique
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppName)
    </div>


    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email):
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>


      <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DevName):
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DevName, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DevName)
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
 <div class="editor-field grid_2 submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="demo-submit-button"/><br />
        @ViewData["DemoMessage"]
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

And here is my model:

```
 public class NewAPIFormModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Email]
        [DisplayName("Developer Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Application Name")]
        public string AppName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Organization Name")]
        public string OrgName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Developer Name")]
        public string DevName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("App Key/ClientID")]
        public string ClientID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Client_Secret")]
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Redirect_url")]
        public string RedUrl { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Application Name")]
        public string AppNameForMP { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Application Description")]
        public string AppDesc { get; set; }
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your model as collection of NewAPIFormModels which does not contain a property as `AppName`. Actually, the objects inside it has that property. You need to have single `NewAPIFormModel` as your model. To do that you should not be using  `ToList()` function to materialize your query.

You should be using either `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` depending on your needs.

```
var viewModel = (linq query here).First();
```

- If you are sure that your select query will always return something than go with `First()` which makes more sense.
- Otherwise go with `FirstOrDefault()` and handle the case when the result is null.

This way that you can get a single `NewAPIFormModel` object instead of collection that is keeping a single  `NewAPIFormModel` object.

In your view define your strongly typed model as following.

```
@model N.Models.NewAPIFormModel
```